# JavaFX getIcon()

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I've been trying to figure out how to position my Stage Icon beside my Stage title. I was unable to formulate a solution for this. How do I get my Icon to be position beside my title?

```
stage.getIcons().add(new Image(""));

stage.setTitle("");
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 50 reputation to add a comment, but you don't really explain what the problem is with your current code. Those are the right methods, but maybe your file locations just aren't right? See the following example:

```
public class MainApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Scene.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/so-icon.png")));
        stage.setTitle("Icon Example");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image: Project layout]

[image: Icon example]

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was. I want the Icon and title to be in the center of the window title bar.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible, since it's the operating system which controls the container. For the title you could write some dirty hacks to add whitespace based on the application's width, but the icon seems improbable. IIRC, title gets automatically centered in Windows 8 as well, but Windows 7 defaults to left allignment.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I guess there isn't much I can do about it then. Could you by any chance help me out with this then? I am currently building a web browser. This is my problem. When I enter a URL like https://hotmail.ca that does not load my progress bar freezes, but it still stays. Basically, I want it where whenever webengine cannot load a page it will   hide or put the progress.toBack();. Thank you! :)

Comment: Since this is another question, I think you're better off with creating a new question related to your new topic. This way you'll get more views and possible responses related to your new problem. As for my opinion on it, I have no experience with web engines so I can't give any useful input on that one.